# What is the Stack Exchange site to ask questions regarding Microsoft Windows?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, windows-7

There is a site dedicated to Linux/Unix (https://unix.stackexchange.com/) and one for Ubuntu (https://askubuntu.com/) as well. I have a question about Windows 7 command line regarding PostgreSQL. In which site shoud I post that?

Comment: It kinda depends what the postgresql question is; it could also be dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: I did this on dba, probably it is much more about postgresql as from win7. Although superuser is very friendly, dba is much more professional.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com or https://dba.stackexchange.com . SU might also help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe that [Super User](https://superuser.com/) would be your best bet here.

As stated in their [about section](https://superuser.com/about):

> Super User is a question and answer site for computer enthusiasts and power users.

I ran a simple query and found 9 posts on the site that have both the [windows7](/questions/tagged/windows7) and [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) tags:
https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7+postgresql